# Woocommerce multistep shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a woocommerce multistep shopping cart. I tried to use [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-multistep-checkout/8125187) plugin(Woocommerce multi step checkout) but It's working only on checkout process.  I need to add it on shopping cart as well. Please follow this image. This is how my shopping cart looks like.

1) I'm selling perfumes. so when someone adds a product to cart I need to display a popup to choose free sample of that product.It also need to add to the cart as a free item.

2) and then I need to follow those 5 steps like this image.

Can someone help me ? Your help is highly appritiated.

Thanks.
 [image]

Comment: were you able to solve this problem yet?

Comment: No.  I still coudn't

Comment: Have you tried combining the multi step checkout with Woocommerce onepage checkout? Logically it should do the trick, but who knows

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post but have a look at the following extension by WooCommerce:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-add-ons/

Might not be a full solution to your requirements but would at least provide you with the functionality you require.

Comment: What I need is to change the checkout process.